# Ajax on Captive Network Assistant on iOS and OSX

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, macos, captivenetwork

Does ajax work on **Captive network Assistant** on iOS and OSX?
I am using **jquery** to do the following, but does not work. 
The 
**responseText**
variable comes neither as true or false. Works fine on proper Safari browser as well as for android and windows devices.

Also, is there any documentation available for **Captive network Assistant**? I am unable to find any on google.

```
function checkEmailHost(hostname) {

    if ($.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "welcome/emailvalidate",
        data : "hostname=" + hostname,
        async : false
    }).responseText == "true") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

From our experimentation it seems like only synchronous calls are "blocked", hence the `async : false` in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I cannot test this or mark it as accepted since I am no longer working on this project. This was in 2013, and I worked around the problem by validating inside the controller class on form submission.