# Captive Portal: AJAX post is very unpredictable

Tags: jquery, ajax, captivenetwork, captiveportal

We're trying to add a registration step when joining a network with a Captive Portal. This is just for desktop, authentication for mobile users is handled by a mobile app. The process works fine when in an ordinary browser, but an AJAX request fails when in the captive portal window.

It seems very random though, I have actually receive success responses using the captive portal window but the majority of the time it returns a failure.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I've no explanation for the non-determinism that you're experiencing, but if you're talking about Apple devices: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843992/ajax-on-captive-network-assistant-on-ios-and-osx) suggests that _asynchronous_ AJAX requests are blocked. Looking at [JQuery's ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): cross-domain requests and JSONP requests cannot be done synchronously, and are therefore blocked by Apple's Captive Network Assistant. only way around that would be to make a same-domain API to proxy the request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is related to your issue but we have noticed a new Captive Network Assistance (CNA) behavior.

Specifically, a splash page that has we UX workflow that requires redirects to several URLs, the CNA will time-out and continue the workflow in a Safari web page.

See our post to Apple Developer Forum [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/137659#137659).

Edited to connect to my account.